# Docker image build fails on file add

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

This is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM debian:latest

LABEL MAINTAINER DINESH

LABEL version="1.0"

LABEL description="First image with Dockerfile & DINESH."

RUN apt-get clean

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -qy git

RUN apt-get install -qy locales

RUN apt-get install -qy nano

RUN apt-get install -qy tmux

RUN apt-get install -qy wget

RUN apt-get install -qy python3

RUN apt-get install -qy python3-psycopg2

RUN apt-get install -qy python3-pystache

RUN apt-get install -qy python3-yaml

RUN apt-get -qy autoremove

# ** ERROR IS BELOW **
ADD .bashrc /root/.bashrc

ADD .profile /root/.profile

ADD app /app

RUN locale-gen C.UTF-8 && /usr/sbin/update-locale LANG=C.UTF-8

ENV PYTHONIOENCODING UTF-8

ENV PYTHONPATH /app/
```

When i run this command `docker build -t myimage .`, it is giving error below.

```
"Step 17/20 : ADD app /app
ADD failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder687980062/.bashrc: no such file or directory"
```

I gave permission the above give path but it is not resolved. Please let me know how I can solve it.

Answer (score 1):

First please make sure file is existing in proper directory. as error suggesting `no such file or directory`

Please instead of ADD try using COPY working for me

```
COPY .bashrc /root/ 
COPY .profile /root/
```

also make file exist at source place and destination is proper.

Also as per best practices you can merge line and make a single command

```
RUN apt-get update -yq \
    && apt-get install -y python3-dev build-essential -yq \
    && apt-get install curl -yq \
    && pip install -r requirements.txt \
    && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove gcc python3-dev build-essential
```

Comment: @Dewa file exist in same directory ? where you are running command ?

Comment: Tried but no luck, getting same issue : COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder365800500/.bashrc: no such file or directory

Comment: OK noted for the best practice guidance, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

change to:

```
ADD .bashrc /root/ 
ADD .profile /root/
ADD app /
```

From documentation:
`ADD src ... dest`.

> The dest is an absolute path, or a path relative
>   to WORKDIR, into which the source will be copied inside the
>   destination container.

Comment: @Lukaz i tried but it is not working. getting same error.

Comment: I see, try it: `ADD ~/.bashrc /root/`

Comment: use COPY once instead of ADD

Comment: same error plz refer the message: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder109742057/~/.bashrc: no such file or directory